# Trying to use a Hashmap<Integer, Integer>

Tags: java, hashmap

how would I increment the key [i] by 1 in this situation every time I run through this for loop with the way I currently have it set up all the elements only get mapped to 1. I am trying to find out how many times each number occurs. I have tried +1 in the empty spot after list.get(i) but again only maps each element to 1. thank you.

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> Mode = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            list.add(arr[i][j]); 
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list);
    int count = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i ++) {
        Mode.put(list.get(i), );
```

Comment: int count = 1 can be ignored!!

Comment: Your question is not very understandable, but comment is good

Comment: haha sorry been working on these assignments since 10AM MT time just out of it thanks for the help I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the option, you may find it easier to use something like [Multiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) from [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html).

```
Multiset<Integer> seen = HashMultiset.create();
for (int[] row : arr) {
  for (int elem : row) {
    seen.add(elem); // none of that nasty dealing with the Map
  }
}
// you can look up the count of an element with seen.count(elem)
E mostCommon = null;
int highestCount = 0;
for (Multiset.Entry<Integer> entry : seen.entrySet()) {
  if (entry.getCount() > highestCount) {
    mostCommon = entry.getElement();
    highestCount = entry.getCount();
  }
}
return mostCommon; // this is the most common element
```

Comment: If you can't use third-party libraries -- which may be the case, if this is a homework assignment -- you should use AVD's solution.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a `Key` here.

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        int value=list.get(i);
        if(!Mode.containsKey(value))
            Mode.put(value,1);
        else
            Mode.put(value,Mode.get(value)+1);
}
```

Comment: @AVD is right on the money.  Or your question is unclear.  From what I understand, you are looking to count the number of occurances a value occurs within your array.  Consequently, you use the value as the key to your map, and then the number of occurances as the map value.  That is precisely what is being suggested.  If this is incorrect, please clarify your question and explain why the solution offered is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

According to your comment,

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i ++) {
   if(Mode.containsKey(list.get(i)) ){
       Integer count = Mode.get(list.get(i));

       Mode.put(list.get(i), ++count);}
   else
       Mode.put(list.get(i), 1);
```